# widget on event updating in Oreo era. (service, file observer)

Tags: android, service, widget

I'm writing widget containing recent photos/images taken on phone.

As it's known widget can update itself as frequently as for every 30min, so I need trigger that calls onUpdate method when some photo appears in external storage. My research provided me to FilesObserver that would run in kind of service.

But I also found info that in newest Android version there are restrictions for keeping background services, so actually I didn't even started implementing things mentioned before.

Have no idea how to resolve that and how it's made on other widgets.

Eventually there might be some other kind of refresh trigger that would be better than 30 min interval...